# How to get the right position of an View for animations?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a set game App. For that, I have a deck of cards from which I want the cards to (animating) move on the board.

My problem is when I do this:

```
   private func createDeck() {
        allCards.forEach{ card in
            card.isFaceUp = false
            card.frame = Deck.frame
            GameBoard.allCardsInDeck.append(card)
        }
    }
```

the cards appearing from another position then the deck.

Doesn´t `Deck.frame` give me the current position of the view in its `superview`? my card appearing from the top but my `deckView` is at the bottom.

this is my code ViewController:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var informationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ScoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Deck: Deck!
    @IBOutlet weak var GameBoard: CardBoardView! {
        didSet {
            let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipe))
            swipeGesture.direction = .down
            GameBoard.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)

            let rotationGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rotation))
            GameBoard.addGestureRecognizer(rotationGesture)
        }
    }

    private var gameIsStarted = false
    private var game: Game = Game() {
        didSet {
            updateScoreLabel()
        }
    }

    private var selectedCards = [CardSubview] ()
    private var indexOfAllCards: Int = 0
    private lazy var allCards = getAllCards()
    private var cardsBackgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

    @objc func rotation(recognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer){
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .ended: GameBoard.mixCards()
        default: break
        }
    }

    @objc private func swipe(recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .ended: add3Cards()
        default: break
        }
    }


    private func getAllCards () -> [CardSubview] {
        var cards = [CardSubview]()
        for index in 0..<game.cards.count {
            cards.append(CardSubview())
            cards[index].fill = game.cards[index].strokeIdentifier
            cards[index].color = game.cards[index].colorIdentifier
            cards[index].form = game.cards[index].form
            cards[index].occurence = game.cards[index].occurenceOfForm
            cards[index].addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tab)))
            cards[index].backgroundColor = cardsBackgroundColor
            cards[index].indexNr = index
        }
        return cards
    }

    @objc private func tab (recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .ended:
            if let card = recognizer.view as? CardSubview, card.isFaceUp == true {
                card.isSelected = !card.isSelected
                if card.isSelected {
                    selectedCards.append(card)
                    if selectedCards.count > 2 {
                        let isSet = game.isSet(arrayOfIndexes: [selectedCards[0].indexNr,selectedCards[1].indexNr, selectedCards[2].indexNr]) == true
                        if isSet {
                            game.score += 1
                            selectedCards.forEach { card in
                                GameBoard.doWhenMatched(card: card)
                                card.isSelected = false
                                selectedCards.removeAll()
                            }
                            findSet()
                        } else if isSet == false {
                            game.score -= 1
                            selectedCards.forEach{ card in
                                card.isSelected = false
                            }
                            selectedCards.removeAll()
                        }
                    }
                } else if card.isSelected == false, selectedCards.contains(card) {
                    selectedCards.remove(at: selectedCards.index(of: card)!)
                }
            }
        default: break
        }
    }

    private func findSet() {
        if GameBoard.allOpenCards.count > 0 {
            var setInOpenCards = Bool()
            var allSetsInOpenCards = Int()
            for index1 in 0..<GameBoard.allOpenCards.count-2 {
                for index2 in (index1+1)..<GameBoard.allOpenCards.count-1 {
                    for index3 in (index2+1)..<GameBoard.allOpenCards.count {
                        setInOpenCards = game.isSet(arrayOfIndexes: [allCards[index1].indexNr, allCards[index2].indexNr, allCards[index3].indexNr])
                        if (setInOpenCards == true){
                            allSetsInOpenCards+=1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            informationLabel.text = "Sets available: \(allSetsInOpenCards)"
        } else {
            informationLabel.text = "Sets available: \(0)"
        }
    }

    @IBAction private func newGame() {
        game = Game()
        GameBoard.removeSubviewsFromDeck()
        GameBoard.allCardsInDeck.removeAll()
        createDeck()
        GameBoard.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        GameBoard.removeSubviews()
        selectedCards.removeAll()
        gameIsStarted = true
        allCards = getAllCards()
        indexOfAllCards = 0
        GameBoard.allOpenCards.removeAll()
        add12Cards()
    }

    private func updateScoreLabel () {
        if game.score >= 0 {
            ScoreLabel.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.9768045545, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        } else if game.score < 0 {
            ScoreLabel.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.1491314173, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        }
        ScoreLabel.text = "Score: \(game.score)"
    }

    private func add3Cards() {
        if indexOfAllCards < allCards.count, gameIsStarted == true {
            for _ in 0...2 {
                GameBoard.allOpenCards.append(GameBoard.allCardsInDeck[indexOfAllCards])
                indexOfAllCards+=1
            }
        }
        findSet()
    }

    private func add12Cards() {
        let numbersOfFirst12Cards = 12
        if gameIsStarted == true {
            for _ in 0..<numbersOfFirst12Cards {
                GameBoard.allOpenCards.append(GameBoard.allCardsInDeck[indexOfAllCards])
                indexOfAllCards += 1
            }
        }
        findSet()
    }

    private func createDeck() {
        allCards.forEach{ card in
            card.isFaceUp = false
            card.frame = Deck.frame
            GameBoard.allCardsInDeck.append(card)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `CardBoardView` where all my animations happening

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable

class CardBoardView: UIView {
    let durationForDisappearingCards = 2.0
    let delayForDisappearingCards = 0.0
    lazy var animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self)
    lazy var cardBehavior = CardBehavior(in: animator)

    var allOpenCards = [CardSubview]() {
        didSet { addSubview(); setNeedsLayout();}
    }

    var allCardsInDeck = [CardSubview] () {
        didSet{ setNeedsLayout()}
    }

    struct Layout {
        static let ratio:CGFloat = 2.0
        static let insetByX:CGFloat = 2.0
        static let insetByY:CGFloat = 2.0
    }

    private func addSubview() {
        for card in allOpenCards {
            addSubview(card)
        }
    }

    public func removeSubviews() {
        for card in allOpenCards {
            card.removeFromSuperview()

        }
    }

    public func removeSubviewsFromDeck() {
        allCardsInDeck.forEach{ card in
            card.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    public func mixCards() {
        var mixCards = [CardSubview]()
        for _ in 0..<allOpenCards.count {
            let random = allOpenCards.count.arc4random
            let card = allOpenCards[random]
            mixCards.append(card)
            allOpenCards.remove(at: random)
        }

        allOpenCards = mixCards

    }




    public func doWhenMatched(card: CardSubview) {
     // cardBehavior.addItem(card)
        UIView.animate(
                    withDuration: self.durationForDisappearingCards,
                    delay: self.delayForDisappearingCards,
                    animations: {

                        card.frame = CGRect(x: (self.superview?.frame.midX)!-card.bounds.width/2, y: (self.superview?.frame.minY)!-card.bounds.height, width: card.bounds.width , height: card.bounds.height)
                }, completion: { finish in
                    card.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.allOpenCards.remove(at: self.allOpenCards.index(of: card)!)

                }
                )
    }


//        let newPosition = CGRect(x: self.frame.midX-card.bounds.width/2 , y: self.frame.minY, width: card.bounds.width, height: card.bounds.height)
//
//
//
//        UIView.animate(withDuration: durationForDisappearingCards, delay: delayForDisappearingCards, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {card.alpha=0.0})




    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        var grid = Grid(layout: .aspectRatio(Layout.ratio), frame: self.bounds)
        grid.cellCount = allOpenCards.count
        var secondsForDelay:CGFloat = 0
        let secondsForFlipCard:CGFloat = 0.5
        for index in allOpenCards.indices {

            if  self.allOpenCards[index].frame != (grid[index]?.insetBy(dx: Layout.insetByX, dy: Layout.insetByY)) ?? CGRect.zero {
                UIView.animate(
                    withDuration: 0.5,
                    delay: TimeInterval(secondsForDelay) ,
                    animations: {self.allOpenCards[index].frame = (grid[index]?.insetBy(dx: Layout.insetByX, dy: Layout.insetByY)) ?? CGRect.zero},
                    completion: {
                        finish in
                        if self.allOpenCards[index].isFaceUp != true {
                            UIView.transition(with: self.allOpenCards[index],
                                              duration: TimeInterval(secondsForFlipCard),
                                              options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft],
                                              animations: {
                                                self.allOpenCards[index].isFaceUp = true
                            }
                            )
                        }
                }
                )
                secondsForDelay+=0.02
            }
        }
    }
}

private extension Int {
    var arc4random: Int {
        if self > 0 {
            return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self)))
        } else if self < 0 {
            return -Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self)))
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}

private extension CGFloat {
    var arc4random: CGFloat {
        if self > 0 {
            return CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self)))
        } else if self < 0 {
            return -CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self)))
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Deck in another view? Check out put of Deck.frame.

Comment: I drag n droped Deck  in to my Storyboard so it should be a subview of my view(viewController) doesn't it?

Comment: If you are calling this from `viewDidLoad` then it might be the issue, try calling it in `viewDidLayoutSubview`

Comment: im calling it when I click the "newGame" Button.

Comment: i edited my Code so you can see more context